# Laravel dynamically creating functions

Tags: laravel, function, dynamic

I have a ServiceProvider:

```
 namespace App\Providers;

    use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

    use \Validator;

    use App\Services\CustomValidator;


    class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
    {
      public function boot() {
        Validator::extend('firstname_fail', 'App\Services\CustomValidator@fullnameFailValidate');
        Validator::extend('lastname_fail', 'App\Services\CustomValidator@lastnameFailValidate');
        Validator::extend('hotel_fail', 'App\Services\CustomValidator@hotelFailValidate');
        Validator::extend('city_fail', 'App\Services\CustomValidator@cityFailValidate');
   }
```

}

I have a model Tourist, which has such attributes: firstname, lastname, hotel, city. And there can be added some other (many) attributes.

*(I know how to get all field names from Tourist model: $array = Schema::getColumnListing('tourists'); )*

So my question is how to make a dynamic creation of:

> Validator::extend('**fieldname_fail**',
>   "App\Services\CustomValidator@**fieldname**FailValidator')

inside the boot() method?

I tried to use magic _call method, but didn't succeed...

Any help appreciated!:)

Comment: I can smell this over the network! So much magic is just bad, when you come back after 30 days you will have no clue how this part of app works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you need something like this.

1. Iterate over table fields (model attributes);
2. Extend validator for each field (model attribute).

Here is a code example:

```
foreach (Schema::getColumnListing('tourists') as $attribute) {
    Validator::extend("{$attribute}_fail", "App\Services\CustomValidator@{$attribute}FailValidator");
}
```

Comment: you a great! It is so simple that I feel studid not figuring it out.

Comment: you made a mistake though: "${$attribute}_fail" shuold be "{$attribute}_fail"
and "${$attribute}FailValidator" should be "{$attribute}FailValidator". Please, correct your answer and I accept it as "right":)